# Where is my memory getting consumed

Tags: iphone, sdk

[alt text  http://img263.imageshack.us/img263/1880/leak.jpg](http://img263.imageshack.us/img263/1880/leak.jpg)
Here is My problem. If you see there is no memory leak but still I get the memory leak for general block as shown. When I click it it gives me the following details where memory leak is due to quartz core. I dont know where I am going wrong since I am not able to see any leaks in the leak bar.

[alt text http://img263.imageshack.us/img263/6813/leak2.jpg](http://img263.imageshack.us/img263/6813/leak2.jpg)

Comment: Could you provide a larger (higher-resolution) picture?  I can't make out which elements your comments are referencing.

Comment: This is the third question you've posted about this topic. You might get more attention and a better, more concise answer if you consolidate all the information you have to provide in one question, instead of creating new questions each time you have more information to provide.

Comment: Agreed.  These console shots don't give us much to go on.  Can you provide the offending code segment as well?

Comment: I am really sorry to bother that much, but thats what I am doing, providing you more information with pictures.I have no intension to disturb unncessarily. Let me know what else info is required, May be I am not getting what do I need to post.

Comment: Jasarien is suggesting you include all the information from your three questions in a single question, to aid those trying to analyze / answer.

I've looked at the console shots, but don't have enough experience with iPhone development to make a recommendation without seeing the code.

So, consider posting the code segment causing the leak, even if you have only a general idea.

Comment: Picture's incredibly small; hard to give much help.

Comment: This really does belong in your original question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1126791/memory-consumption-keeps-increasing-while-running-application

Answer (score 2):

Bear in mind that the reason you see a 'leak' might be objects allocated to an AutoRelease pool.  Libraries such as Three20 are particularly fond of this for image caching.  If that is the case, the memory in question won't be released until there is a direct need for it (i.e. autorelease drain).

If you keep using your app, do you see a steady memory use climb, until a crash? Or do you see it like a sawtooth - i.e. going up, then suddenly down, then back up again?

Comment: Well thats what my concern is, I am looking at the climb and not the sawtooth. A climb without any memory leaks being reflected. But memory keeep going up.

Answer (score 0):

This looks like a case of an autorelease pool expanding and never draining. Hard to recommend anything without knowing about the particulars of your app (does it use multiple screens and tables or is it a single pane utility or game, etc.)

What you may consider doing is at logical points in your app -- for example when performing a single task -- create a new autorelease pool and use it only for the duration of that task, then release the pool. This will help keep your total memory down and give you better control over resources.

Also, if the app uses multiple view controllers, for example if you're bringing up a modal view or cascading treeviews, you can create the controller for the new view but then set a delegate on the viewcontroller that gets notified when the work is done so you can dispose of the whole controller and view instead of keeping it around.

Finally, if dealing with a lot of images you may want to create a sort of file-system-based caching mechanism with a fixed number of in-memory slots so you only keep data in memory that you absolutely need.